# Sum IF and CASE in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table with Columns artikelnummer = item number, artikelbeschreibung=item description, renr = renr (its the Invoice Number).
What I'm doing I check for values (PN#, RT#, ST#) in the item description and if so, I will give the Value 2 for ST#, 1 for RT#, 3 for PN# else 0. For That, I' doing the CASE.
What I want to do is get the SUM from my Case with the same Invoicnumer.
But I don't get this, I get the total SUM.
What I'm doing wrong.

Note some Columns are missing.
Because I intend to avoid making it too complex.
But if need it, I can give an example of all the Columns and all the Code.

| artikelnummer | artikelbeschreibung | renr | Current Result | Result I want |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1010 | REnr. 1234567 | 2345678 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | GN 2345678 #ST #1234567 | 2345678 | 0 | 0 |
| 1234 | REnr. 1234567 | 2345678 | 253 | 2 |

Note even so, the first Entry starts with REnr, It's got a 0 because of WHEN-Clause early in my CASE statement.

```
CASE
WHEN THEN 
--  Until this point, everything is working.
SELECT  Sum(CASE
         WHEN Try_convert(
              int, [artikelnummer]) <> 0
              AND LEFT([artikelbeschreibung], 2) = 'GN' THEN 0
         WHEN Charindex('GN', [artikelbeschreibung]) > 0
              AND Charindex('ST#', [artikelbeschreibung]) > 0 THEN 2
         WHEN Charindex('GN', [artikelbeschreibung]) > 0
              AND Charindex('RT#', [artikelbeschreibung]) > 0 THEN 1
         WHEN Charindex('GN', [artikelbeschreibung]) > 0
              AND Charindex('PN#', [artikelbeschreibung]) > 0 THEN 3
         ELSE 0
                     END) AS result
          FROM   e_auftragseingang
          WHERE  [renr] =  e_auftragseingang.[renr]
```

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. It isn't clear how `253` is produced from your sample data and code. Perhaps you oversimplified your example. Asides: It's curious that you are checking for the presence of `'ST#'`, but your sample data contains `'#ST'` (or `'ST #'`). And it's a [`case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) _expression_. There is no `case` _statement_ in TSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way,

```
SELECT [renr],
       Sum(CASE WHEN Try_convert(int, [artikelnummer]) <> 0 AND LEFT([artikelbeschreibung], 2) = 'GN' THEN 0
                WHEN Charindex('GN', [artikelbeschreibung]) > 0 AND Charindex('ST#', [artikelbeschreibung]) > 0 THEN 2
                WHEN Charindex('GN', [artikelbeschreibung]) > 0 AND Charindex('RT#', [artikelbeschreibung]) > 0 THEN 1
                WHEN Charindex('GN', [artikelbeschreibung]) > 0 AND Charindex('PN#', [artikelbeschreibung]) > 0 THEN 3
                ELSE 0 END) AS result
FROM   e_auftragseingang
GROUP BY [renr]
```

*Hope you will fix the issue :)*

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to calculate a sum of values based on certain conditions in the artikelbeschreibung column and group them by the renr column. However, there are a few issues with your SQL code.

Firstly, your CASE statement is missing the condition for the first entry. You mentioned that it should have a value of 0, but this is not reflected in your code.

Secondly, you are using a subquery within your CASE statement. This is not necessary since you are already querying the e_auftragseingang table in your main query.

To calculate the sum of values based on the conditions and group them by the renr column, you can modify your code as follows:

```
    SELECT [renr], SUM(CASE
    WHEN TRY_CONVERT(int, [artikelnummer]) <> 0
        AND LEFT([artikelbeschreibung], 2) = 'GN' THEN 0
    WHEN CHARINDEX('GN', [artikelbeschreibung]) > 0
        AND CHARINDEX('ST#', [artikelbeschreibung]) > 0 THEN 2
    WHEN CHARINDEX('GN', [artikelbeschreibung]) > 0
        AND CHARINDEX('RT#', [artikelbeschreibung]) > 0 THEN 1
    WHEN CHARINDEX('GN', [artikelbeschreibung]) > 0
        AND CHARINDEX('PN#', [artikelbeschreibung]) > 0 THEN 3
    ELSE 0
END) AS result
FROM e_auftragseingang
GROUP BY [renr];
```